# How attoparsec can return values of different types?

Tags: haskell, existential-type, attoparsec

I'm stuck with attoparsec where I can't return a value regarding it's "embedded type".

I attempt to parse a file of kind:

```
type
value
type
value
...
```

For example:

```
0 -- code for a string value
hello
70 -- code for an int value
10
0
world
20 -- code for a double value
5.20
```

My current data types are:

```
data KeyValue = forall a. (Typeable a, Show a, Eq a) => KeyValue (Int, a)
instance Eq KeyValue where -- as I need to test equality
    KeyValue (code1, value1) == KeyValue (code2, value2) =
      code1 == code2 && case cast value2 of
                               Just value2' -> value1 == value2
                               Nohing -> False
```

My parser looks like:

```
parser :: Parser [KeyValue]
parser = many' (keyValue <* endOfLine)

keyValue :: Parser KeyValue
keyValue = do
    key <- decimal <* endOfLine
    value <- case key of
               0  -> takeLine
               20 -> double
               70 -> decimal
               _ -> takeLine
    return $ KeyValue (key, value)

takeLine :: Parser Text
takeLine = takeTill isEndOfLine
```

But GHC complains that:

```
Couldn't match type Double with Text
Expected type: Parser Text Text
  Actual type: Parser Double
In the expression: double
In a case alternative: 20 -> double
```

I understand *why* but doesn't know **how** to fix that!

At the moment, I use `ExistantialQuantification` pragma with `Data.Typeable`, but I'm not really sure the solution need to be *"so complex"* with that problem?

Comment: If you really want to use existential quantification, then you need to apply `KeyValue` immediately in the case branch. For example `0 -> takeLine >>= \val -> KeyValue (key, val)`. But you probably just want a sum type.

Comment: Thanks you very much. In fact it was more a syntax error... And by proofreading (again) my question, the file I need to parser was *too reduced*. Anyway, I need to use a sum of existentials quantifications type, right now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a sum type and have your parser return that, e.g.:

```
data SumType = Str String | Int Int | Double Double

keyvalue :: Parser SumType
keyvalue = ...
```

Now `keyvalue` can end with `return (Str "foo")` to indicate that a string has been parsed or with `return (Int 23)`, etc. to indicate that an int has been parsed.

E.g. something like:

```
keyValue = do
    key <- decimal <* endOfLine
    case key of
      20 -> do d <- parseDouble; return (Double d)
      70 -> do i <- parseInt; return (Int i)
      ...
```

Comment: You can use `20 -> Double <$> parseDouble` etc.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen You're right; apologies. I don't know why I wrote that. I'll delete my earlier comment.